# Multipolygon shapefile - Border problem in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1

I am analyzing a shapefile which shows a state of my country. The state shapefile also contains lots of different districs.

Now I want to have an border only for the state. But when I activate the border, ArcMap creates borders around the different districts, not around the whole state.
But I want border around extent of the state, not district. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like polygon to line? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here... could you put in a picture/graphic explaining the situation please.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112209/symbolizing-multiple-polygons-as-one-by-dropping-internal-boundaries i.e. looking for DROPLINE functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "activate the border"?  Are you perhaps talking about selecting it, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to [dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000) the districts into a single polygon.

If you have an advanced license you can use [Polygon to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003t000000) to extract the boundary as a line.

If you don't have advanced then you can [create a line feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002p000000), open it in ArcMap as well as the dissolved polygon, start editing on the line features then copy and paste the polygon into the line feature class, this will copy the boundary of the polygon into the lines. Now save edits and you have your boundary as a line.

Comment: If the border is just for graphical purposes, there's no reason to go all the way down the line route. Just need to dissolve the polygons to a new polygon, make sure that layer is above the other in the ToC, and then symbolize it with an outline and no fill.

Comment: That works too @ChrisW, it wasn't clear from the question what the border was needed for. That and a one-line answer would attract derision.

Comment: Thank you Michael & @Chris W . It was just for graphical purposes :-)

Comment: Then as @ChrisW indicated there's no need to go any further than dissolve. Glad we could help.